# Custom Paging parameters in Extjs4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, paging

In Ext 4, whenever you call

```
store.loadPage(1)
```

Ext seems to set the paging parameters `start` and `limit` in the request for me.

However I need `page` and `pageSize` as the keys for my request parameters. This is how the server handles paging and I have little control over it.

Is there a way I can use such custom paging parameters instead of the default ones provided by Ext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Evan answered, but with a concrete example:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Requests', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    model:'MyApp.model.Request',
    autoLoad:false,
    remoteSort:true,
    proxy:{
        type:'ajax',
        url:'request/list.json',
        //override default param names
        startParam:"offset",
        limitParam:"max",
        sortParam:"sort",
        simpleSortMode:true, //required for directionParam to be used
        directionParam:"order",
        reader:{
            type:'json',
            root:'data'
        }

    },
    pageSize:25
});
```

Comment: how do I get the values of this default params? (limit, start, sort)

Comment: not sure what you mean, can you ask a specific question with your code sample?

Answer (score 5):

This is covered in the docs: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax

See pageParam/limitParam/startParam

To prevent a particular param from sending, set the name to undefined.

Comment: I had to accept DmitryB's answer owing to the code example. But i can still vote up you answer for being the first and right one. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me, added below two params in store's proxy field:

```
startParam : "startIndex",
limitParam : "limitCount"
```